# Adobe Animate CC to PHP

Tags: actionscript-3

Flash AS3 Form Components - PHP File and Adobe Animate

> Symbol 'wholeForm', Layer 'Action', Frame 1, Line 81, Column 3    1120:
>   Access of undefined property varLoader. Symbol 'wholeForm', Layer
>   'Action', Frame 1, Line 81,   Column 18   1120: Access of undefined
>   property varSend. Symbol 'wholeForm', Layer 'Action', Frame 1, Line
>   30,   Column 27   1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type
>   flash.net:URLRequest to an unrelated type Class.

'wholeForm' Is an `MovieClip` that contains buttons and text, see the image below

Program for submiting data to php:[image]

> > code :

```
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//hide processing mc
processing_mc.visible = false;
//custom function we create to populate the comboBox 
list
function addCountriesToList(): void {
    countryList.addItem({
        label: "Barja"
    });
    countryList.addItem({
        label: "Baasir"
    });
    countryList.addItem({
       label: "Jadra"
    });
    countryList.addItem({
       label: "Jieh"
    });
}
// Run function above now
addCountriesToList();

var variables: URLVariables = new URLVariables;

// Build the varSend variable
varSend: URLRequest = new URLRequest("from_parse.php");
varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
varSend.data = variables;

// Build the varLoader variable
varLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader;
varLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

// handler for the PHP script completion and return of status
function completeHandler(event: Event): void {
    // remove processing clip
    processing_mc.visible = false;
    name_txt.text = "";
    email_txt.text = "";
    msg_txt.text = "";
    //msg_txt.maxChars=300;
    kids.value = 0;
    checkBox.selected = false;

    // Load the response frome php here
    status_txt.text = event.target.data.return_msg;
}

// Add event listener for sumbit button click
sumbit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ValidateAndSend);

// function ValidateAndSend
function ValidateAndSend(event: MouseEvent): void {

    // validate fields
    if (!name_txt.length) {
        status_txt.text = "Plase enter your name";
    } else if (!email_txt.length) {
        status_txt.text = "Plase enter your mail";
    } else if (!msg_txt.length) {
        status_txt.text = "Plase enter your message";
    } else {
        // All is good, send the data now to PHP
        processing_mc.visible = true;
        // ready the variables in our form for sending
        variables.userName = name_txt.text;
        variables.userEmail = email_txt.text;
        variables.userCountry = countryList.value;
        variables.userKids = kids.value;
        variables.userGender = radioGroup.value;
        variables.Newsletter = checkBox.selected;

        // Send the data to PHP now
        varLoader.load(varSend);
    } // close else conditin for error handling
} // close validate and send function
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is **no explanation of problem**, I'm guessing you mean you have these errors?

> - Access of undefined property `varLoader`.
> - Access of undefined property `varSend`.
> - Implicit coercion of a value of type `flash.net:URLRequest` to an unrelated type Class

They speak for themselves. You did not declare the variables so they are undefined...

Declare as : `var NAME : TYPE = VALUE;`

Example : `var myLoader : URLLoader = new URLLoader;` defines a variable named `myLoader`.

Your Code example:

```
// Build the varSend variable
varSend: URLRequest = new URLRequest("from_parse.php");
varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
varSend.data = variables;
```

Should be

```
// Build the varSend variable
var varSend: URLRequest = new URLRequest("from_parse.php");
varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
varSend.data = variables;
```

So the fixes are :

- code : varLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader;
  fixed : `var varLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader`;
- code : varSend: URLRequest = new URLRequest("from_parse.php");
  fixed : `var varSend: URLRequest = new URLRequest("from_parse.php");`
- The above `var varSend` (now defined) will also fix error from : `varLoader.load(varSend);`

**PS:**
It would be more helpful (to you & future readers) to make your code more readable like so:

```
// Build the Sending variable
var mySend: URLRequest = new URLRequest("from_parse.php");
mySend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
mySend.data = variables;

// Build the Loading variable
var myLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader;
myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

// Send the data to PHP now
myLoader.load(mySend);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/2057709. Accepting working Answers will improve your chances of more help in future.